# How to make an unboxed array of floats I can get a Ptr to

Tags: c, arrays, opengl, haskell, unboxing

I am trying to do some work with HopenGL and I need a Ptr that points to a array of floats. From what I have read uarray and storableArray seem to be the way to go, in some combination some way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether you already have an array and need a pointer to it or you want to create one.

If you need to create an array and then get a pointer to it you can indeed use storable arrays. In order to create it, use the classes and helperfunctions defined `Data.Array.MArray`. `StorableArray` is an instance of the `MArray` class so all those function can be used to create and manipulate the array. When you want to get the `Ptr` to the array, use the `withStorableArray` function.

I hope that fits your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Storable arrays or Foreign arrays (in Foreign.*) you are able to get a pointer to pass to C or friends.